# How to style Scrollview for QCombobox?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qcombobox

I need to apply style sheet for the `QCombobox`. Can anyone please give
me an example? I thought using the `QScrollView` will affect the
`QCombobox` but it didn't. And how to limit the number of items shown in
a combo box?

Answer (score 0):

You should start from official [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox) for QCombobox stylesheets. Basically it is like:

```
QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 1px 18px 1px 3px;
    min-width: 6em;
}

QComboBox:editable {
    background: white;
}
```

You can limit number of visible items in QComboBox by using [maxVisibleItems](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#maxVisibleItems-prop) property.